# Event listener only triggers correctly after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener that listens for clicks on a group of radio buttons, then passes the checked value to a function.

I then output the checked value to the web console whenever a radio button is selected, but this only works if the radio button is clicked twice after page load.

```js
var t1q1El = document.getElementById("t1q1");

function question_1() {
  $(function(){
    $("#t1q1").one('click',function(){
     var t1q1UserInput = $("input[name=t1q1]:checked").val();
     questionsData['question_1']['input'] = t1q1UserInput;
     assessPoints('question_1', t1q1UserInput);
   });
  });
}

t1q1El.addEventListener("click", question_1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset id="t1q1">
    <label>Strongly Agree
     <input type="radio" value="strongly-agree" name="t1q1">
   </label>
   <label>Agree
     <input type="radio" value="agree" name="t1q1">
   </label>
   <label>No Stance
     <input type="radio" value="no-stance" name="t1q1">
   </label>
   <label>Disagree
     <input type="radio" value="disagree" name="t1q1">
   </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

On the second click, the value is passed to the web console immediately after clicking. All consecutive clicks function as expected. Why doesn't the first click trigger anything?

I'm still learning JS so please excuse/correct any bad practices..

Comment: looks like ytou are combining raw DOM and jQuery. I might not do that - work with one technique.  It also looks like the eventListener is added on a click, which when invoked adds the jQuery.one listener which does the work.

Comment: @akaphenom thanks heaps that makes sense, I'll get replace the jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happening:

1) `t1q1El.addEventListener("click", question_1);` You assign a function to `t1q1El`. Basically you are saying do `question_1` when `t1q1El` is clicked.

2) Click 1. We do `question_1` which is assigning a click event to `t1qE1`. Now t1qE1 has 2 events.

3) Click 2. Doing `question_1` (which is assigning another click event on itself) and executing that click.

Solution is simple to just assign a click event:

```
 $(function(){
        $("#t1q1").one('click',function(){
            var t1q1UserInput = $("input[name=t1q1]:checked").val();
            questionsData['question_1']['input'] = t1q1UserInput;
            assessPoints('question_1', t1q1UserInput);
        });
});
```

BTW [one()](https://api.jquery.com/one/) will execute only once, if you need to keep the event after first executions use [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that makes sense!